# Descend x-axis values using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

How can I plot a bar graph where the x-axis values are in descending order from highest to lowest?

Example:

For example purposes, my plot is graphed as so:

[image: graph]

I need the graph to sort where it plots Monday(highest value), Wednesday, Tuesday(smallest value) (respectively)

Here's what I have so far:

```
x_axis = ['a','b','c'...'z']
y_axis = [#...#...#] number values for each letter in xaxis

def barplot(x_axis, y_axis): #x and y axis defined in another function
    x_label_pos = range(len(y_axis))
    plot.bar(x_label_pos, y_axis)
    plot.yticks(range(0, int(max(y_axis) + 2), 2))
    plot.xticks(x_axis)
```

Comment: The simple answer would be that you need to sort the values output by `numpy.histogram` and keep track of the indexes that represent the days of the week. However without some example code, it is impossible to give you a clear answer. Please post a minimal example of what you have right now.

Answer (score 10):

```
# grab a reference to the current axes
ax = plt.gca()
# set the xlimits to be the reverse of the current xlimits
ax.set_xlim(ax.get_xlim()[::-1])
# call `draw` to re-render the graph
plt.draw()
```

`matplotlib` will 'do the right thing' if you set the x limits with left value being greater than the right value (and the same with the y-axis).

Comment: Can you please describe what each line does? I'm confused where ax and plt.gca() come from or stand for. Thanks.

Comment: That code reverses the x-axis, my intended outcome should descend the values from largest to smallest, the largest value on the left and the smallest at the very right.

Comment: How are those two things different?  Please show a (minimal) example of what you are doing now that is not working.

Answer (score 0):

So below is a minimal example that will do what you need. Your problem is actually nothing to do with matplotlib, but is just a case of reordering your input data as desired.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# some dummy lists with unordered values 
x_axis = ['a','b','c']
y_axis = [1,3,2]

def barplot(x_axis, y_axis): 
    # zip the two lists and co-sort by biggest bin value         
    ax_sort = sorted(zip(y_axis,x_axis), reverse=True)
    y_axis = [i[0] for i in ax_sort]
    x_axis = [i[1] for i in ax_sort]

    # the above is ugly and would be better served using a numpy recarray

    # get the positions of the x coordinates of the bars
    x_label_pos = range(len(x_axis))

    # plot the bars and align on center of x coordinate
    plt.bar(x_label_pos, y_axis,align="center")

    # update the ticks to the desired labels
    plt.xticks(x_label_pos,x_axis)


barplot(x_axis, y_axis)
plt.show()
```